# JavaFx Controller initialization is not working in proper order

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am working on a Desktop application using JavaFX 2.2. I have an application class which loads the main fxml. In that main fxml i had a Border pane and in the center part, i had included a child fxml, using `<fx:include>`. My problem is that, the child fxml's controller initialize method is getting called before the parent controller's. I need to get the parent to be initialized when its loaded in the application class. I dont know whether its the actual or behavior or i need to do something else to get it works done. I am really new to the JavaFX.

Below is my sample code.

//Main Application class

```
public class DemoApplication extends Application {

    static double stage_width, stage_height;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Rectangle2D primScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        stage_width = primScreenBounds.getWidth();
        stage_height = primScreenBounds.getHeight();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
        stage.setX(0);
        stage.setY(0);
        stage.setWidth(primScreenBounds.getWidth());
        stage.setHeight(primScreenBounds.getHeight());
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

//Main Controller

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {
 @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
       System.out.println("Initializing the parent controller");
    }
}
```

//Child Controller

```
public class ChildController implements Initializable {
 @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
       System.out.println("Initializing the child controller");
    }
}
```

//Main Fxml

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="ap_screen" prefHeight="821.0000999999975" prefWidth="1395.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="com.demo.app.controller.MainController">
  <children>
    <BorderPane fx:id="bp" prefHeight="754.0" prefWidth="1282.0">
      <center>
        <Pane fx:id="p2_cen" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
          <children>
            <HBox fx:id="p1_cen" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="523.0" styleClass="hb">
              <children>
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Favourite" textFill="WHITE" HBox.margin="$x2" />
              </children>
              <stylesheets>
                <URL value="@styles.css" />
              </stylesheets>
            </HBox>
            **<fx:include source="child.fxml" layoutY="100.0" />**
          </children>
        </Pane>
      </center>
      <left>
        <VBox fx:id="vb_left" prefHeight="419.0" prefWidth="200.0" styleClass="vbox">
          <children>
            <ComboBox fx:id="combo" onAction="#combo" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="200.0" styleClass="combo">
              <stylesheets>
                <URL value="@styles.css" />
              </stylesheets>
            </ComboBox>
          </children>
          <stylesheets>
            <URL value="@styles.css" />
          </stylesheets>
        </VBox>
      </left>
      <top>
        <HBox fx:id="hb_top" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="500.0" styleClass="hbox">
        </HBox>
      </top>
    </BorderPane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

//child fxml

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="457.0" prefWidth="619.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="com.demo.app.controller.ChildController">
    <children>
        <ScrollPane fx:id="sp1" fitToWidth="true" layoutY="189.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="364.0">
            <content>
                <AnchorPane id="Content" prefHeight="241.0" prefWidth="435.0">
                    <children>
                        <VBox fx:id="vbmain" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="174.0" />
                        <Button id="b1" fx:id="b2" layoutY="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#movleft" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="40.0" text="Button" />
                        <Button id="b2" fx:id="b1" layoutX="246.0" layoutY="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#movright" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="40.0" text="Button" />
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </content>
        </ScrollPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively, children are instanciated before the parent: to layout correcly the parent FXML, the children have to be processed first (drawing the parent implies drawing the children first).

If you want to maintain some kind of state from the parent component that modifies its children, you can put the state in a singleton that you can use in both the parent and children at any moment you want, there are many examples of Spring integration with JavaFX.